# Parsing text in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple containing blog posts, which looks something like this:

```
[('category1', 'blablablabla'), ('Category2', 'bla bla bla'), ('category1', 'blabla')].
```

Now I need to get the most frequent words *per category* from this, however I am unable to tokenize the words without losing the categories.
Standard ways to tokenize fail on a tuple, I have used the parser from nltk and the .split() way, but both do not work for a tuple.
Can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a function `tokenize` that returns tokens when given a string:

```
for cat, text in tuples:
    tokenized = tokenize(text)
    # now do whatever you want with the category and the tokenized text
```